# How can I have field names on extract data Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a question: Why does Tableau show the technical name when on extract but shows the field name on live? I also want to know how to fix this so that I could have field names in extract without manually renaming.

Thank you

Comment: Your question is very confusing. What do you mean by technical name vs field name?

Comment: The field name is the name that your average human understands for example: Customer Name.

Comment: The technical name is the one that machines understand for example: custname.